# How to select a random row in SQL except selecting a particular id?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am having trouble in finding the right code for my website. I want to fetch random row from a SQL data base using a PHP code and also I want the code to select any random row except the row with a particular ID.
This is the code that I came up with:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
?>
```

I want this code to select any row except the row whose id = 1.

Comment: Do you mean you want to exclude a certain row? Dont know what you mean by "accept the row whose id=1". If you mean "except id=1" then add `where id <> 1`.

Comment: I mean that same thing and can you tell me that <> symbol means is not equal to?

Comment: If you want to remove the first result in random search, you can use **LIMIT** query like this `SELECT coulmn FROM table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1,1`. This will remove the first result from random selection

Comment: Yes <> means not equal. You can also use !=

Comment: _“and can you tell me that <> symbol means is not equal to?”_ - please don’t get into the habit of asking about such basics here, this is stuff you should easily be able to read up on, on your own. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: I think you mean 'except'

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name
where id <> 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```